# Difference between wiring events with and without "new"

Tags: c#, events, syntax, delegates

In C#, what is the difference (if any) between these two lines of code?

```
tmrMain.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(tmrMain_Tick);
```

and

```
tmrMain.Elapsed += tmrMain_Tick;
```

Both appear to work exactly the same. Does C# just assume you mean the former when you type the latter?

Comment: Well, they both work alright. Then why does Visual Studio choose the former over the latter when it auto creates the event handler stub?

Comment: That feature dates back from before Visual Studio 2005, which introduced the shorter syntax.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I did this

```
static void Hook1()
{
    someEvent += new EventHandler( Program_someEvent );
}

static void Hook2()
{
    someEvent += Program_someEvent;
}
```

And then ran ildasm over the code.
The generated MSIL was exactly the same.

So to answer your question, yes they are the same thing.
The compiler is just inferring that you want `someEvent += new EventHandler( Program_someEvent );`
-- You can see it creating the new `EventHandler` object in both cases in the MSIL

Answer (score 5):

It used to be (.NET 1.x days) that the long form was the only way to do it. In both cases you are newing up a delegate to point to the Program_someEvent method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any difference. Certainly resharper says the first line has redundant code.

Answer (score 2):

A little offtopic :

You could instantiate a delegate `(new EventHandler(MethodName))` and (if appropriate) reuse that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't the `new XYZEventHandler` require until C#2003, and you were allowed to omit the redundant code in C#2005?

Answer (score -1):

I think the one way to really tell would be to look at the MSIL produced for the code.. Tends to be a good acid test..

I have funny concerns that it may somehow mess with GC.. Seems odd that there would be all the overhead of declaring the new delegate type if it never needed to be done this way, you know?