# Attaching Eventhandler with New Handler vs Directly assigning it

Tags: c#, events, syntax

What is the actual difference, advantages and disadvantages, of creating a new event handler, vs assigning it directly to the event?

```
_gMonitor.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
```

vs

```
_gMonitor.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Difference between ' += anEvent' and ' += new EventHandler(anEvent)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550703/c-difference-between-anevent-and-new-eventhandleranevent)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C# 2.0 and above, they are identical. In C# 1.2 (the one that shipped with .NET 1.1), only the first syntax (with `new`) compiles ;-p

The second syntax saves key presses, but VS intellisense will typically suggest the first. Ultimately, it makes very little difference. I generally use the second syntax in code-samples online, simply because it avoids going over the (narrow) column width!

Comment: I think the first one creates memory leak issues, but I cannot find anything to prove this. But I have faced such issues in past the windows service was not closing just because the `timer.Tick += new Handler_Tick(timer_TickMethod);` was not `timer.Tick += timer_TickMethod;` and unsubscribing was not helpful thus with `timer.Tick += new Handler_Tick(timer_TickMethod);`.

Comment: @HarshBaid you are incorrect; they compile to ***exactly*** the same thing. For info, delegate unsubscription is based on a match on the MethodInfo and *instance*; it doesn't need to be the same actual delegate instance to correctly unsubscribe

Comment: how about `_gMonitor.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged` or `_gMonitor.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged)`, will it work with the first option?

Comment: @mark hm I think you are right, I would have mixed it with unsubscribe event handler. :P

Comment: @LouisRhys again, other than "one is a subscribe, one is an unsubscribe", they are identical

Answer (score 4):

The compiler has enough information available to make the `new EventHandler` effectively [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

It knows that you are attaching an event handler to an event, as only `+=` and `-=` are valid at this point, so you don't need tell it what to do.