# C# adding event handler using v.s. not using new keyword

Tags: c#, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877/c-event-handlers)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Attaching Eventhandler with New Handler vs Directly assigning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884595/c-attaching-eventhandler-with-new-handler-vs-directly-assigning-it)

Hi,

May I know what is the difference between using new keyword and not using, in for example:

```
this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(HandlerTabPageSelection);
this.MouseWheel += HandlerTabPageSelection;
```

Thanks.