# When adding an Event Handler, use 'new()' or not?

Tags: c#, event-handling, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attaching Eventhandler with New Handler vs Directly assigning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884595/attaching-eventhandler-with-new-handler-vs-directly-assigning-it)

What is the difference between assigning a callback to, lets say a button's *Click* event by using `+= new(...)` versus just `+=`? Here are samples of each for clarity:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);
b.Click += button_Click;
```

Does the first one create a new instance of the method `button_Click` whereas the second always uses the one defined in *this*?

Answer (score 7):

The second one is short hand for the first one, so both will create the event handler and add it to `Click`.

Here's a [good explanation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) from the chapter on events in "C# in Depth."

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

You could also do..

```
b.Click += (e, sender) =>{
 // do something here
};
```

All three are the same, i.e. assigning a function to a delegate.

Comment: yah but you cant detach properly asaik