# using handler constructor in event listener: What is the difference?

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attaching Eventhandler with New Handler vs Directly assigning it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884595/attaching-eventhandler-with-new-handler-vs-directly-assigning-it)

I noticed there are two possible way to add an event listener:

```
List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
```

or simply,

```
List.Changed += ListChanged;
```

What is the difference between these two declaration?

The autocomplete in Visual Studio generates the former, but I wonder whether they have different behaviour. Beside, if we use the former, how do we remove the listener? If we use the latter, `List.Changed -= ListChanged`; will work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will generate the same IL, so there is **no** difference. In the shorter example, the compiler automatically infers the delegate type to be used.

Removing the listener is equally interchangable:

```
// both will work the same way, no matter which one was used to register the handler
List.Changed -= ListChanged;
List.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, the second form is just a bit simpler (less code).