# C# new [delegate] not necessary?

Tags: c#, delegates

I've been playing with `HttpWebRequest`s lately, and in the tutorials they always do:

```
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(
  new AsyncCallback(UpdateItem),state);
```

But `new AsyncCallback` doesn't seem to be necesary. If `UpdateItem` has the right signature, then there doesn't seem to be a problem. So why do people include it? Does it do anything at all?

Comment: I don't normally use `new DelegateType(...)`, would also like to know if that does anything. MSDN doesn't really talk about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Difference between ' += anEvent' and ' += new EventHandler(anEvent)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550703/c-difference-between-anevent-and-new-eventhandleranevent)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's the same thing, mostly (there are a few overload rules to think about, although not in this simple example). But in previous versions of C#, there wasn't any delegate type inference. So the tutorial was either (a) written before delegate type inference was available, or (b) they wanted to be verbose for explanation purposes.

Here's a summary of a few of the different ways you can take advantage of delegate type inferencing:

```
// Old-school style.
Chef(new CookingInstructions(MakeThreeCourseMeal));

// Explicitly make an anonymous delegate.
Chef(delegate { MakeThreeCourseMeal });

// Implicitly make an anonymous delegate.
Chef(MakeThreeCourseMeal);

// Lambda.
Chef(() => MakeThreeCourseMeal());

// Lambda with explicit block.
Chef(() => { AssembleIngredients(); MakeThreeCourseMeal(); AnnounceDinnerServed(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

[AsyncCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx) is just a delegate in C#, it is declared as

```
public delegate void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar);
```

When you pass the method name itself as long as the signature matches the compiler will usually substitute the code for you, its just shortcut.

You can simply check this using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). If you have this for example.

```
request.BeginGetResponse(TestMethod, null);

 static void (IAsyncResult r)
        {
           //do something
        }
```

The compiled code will actually look like this.

```
   request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Test), null);
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, this changes between C# 1.2 (with .NET 1.1) and C# 2.0 (with .NET 2.0). So from 2.0 onwards you can indeed omit the `new SomeDelegateType(...)` in most scenarios. Oddly, the tooling hasn't changed, so in the IDE if you type `someObj.SomeEvent +=` the IDE will suggest (via <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>) the full version including delegate type.