# what is the difference between "MouseDown+=new MouseEventHandler(mouseDown)" and MouseDown+=mouseDown

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

While i am using resharper he always say

[image]

what is the difference?

any details will be nice

Thanks for you all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [+= new EventHandler(Method) vs += Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749868/new-eventhandlermethod-vs-method) or [Should I instantiate a new delegate or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676399/should-i-instantiate-a-new-delegate-or-not) or [Difference between wiring events using “new EventHandler<T>” and not using new EventHandler<T>"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468868/difference-between-wiring-events-using-new-eventhandlert-and-not-using-new-e)

Comment: Or [C#: Difference between ' += anEvent' and ' += new EventHandler(anEvent)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550703/c-difference-between-anevent-and-new-eventhandleranevent)

Comment: bc resharper is a bloated hog eating your cpu like dorritos // only slightly sarcastic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shorter syntax has been introduced in C# 2.0 and it's just a syntactic sugar of the longer form.

No matter what you write, the result is always the same. However, the shorter is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

There really is no difference.  The "new MouseEventHandler" part is implied.