# Two ways of defining a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [very simple delegate musing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709721/very-simple-delegate-musing)

I've been wondering what's the difference between this method of defining a delegate

```
System.Action act;
act = MethodWithoutParameters;
```

and this one

```
System.Action act;
act = new System.Action(MethodWithoutParameters);
```

. Should I prefer one over the other? If so, why?
I have unfortunately not been able to find much information regarding my question.
I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me the differences between those two pieces of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's syntactic sugar: an "implicit method group conversion".  The compiler transforms the first version into the second.

Answer (score 4):

These two pieces of code produce the exact same IL.  There is no reason to prefer one over the other.  It is simply a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

It's exatcly the same, **there is no difference**

I would add also the *third one*, lambda !:

```
System.Action act = x=>DoSomething(x);
```

Comment: That one is slightly different. It introduces a lambda expression, making the delegate point to a method which in turn calls the DoSomething method. There are several (admittedly obscure) cases where this is functionally different.

Comment: @ChrisShain: If this could be different, so declaring the same `lambda` inside ordinary function declared like a `delegate` *should* lead to same obscure results. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking

Comment: I mean, why this example would be different from those ones presented before, if I put **this** lambda notion inside a function. Like, for example `act = MethodWithoutParameters` inside `MethodWithoutParameters` I have a lambda call `x=>DoSomething(s);` ?

Comment: Passing parameters makes no difference, if that's what you mean.

Comment: One functional difference between the lambda and non-lambda version is caching. In certain cases the C# compiler will cache the result of a lambda expression as a static field.  It will never cache either of the two cases in the question.

Comment: @JarerPar: Guys, sure: there is a cashing, there is a lazy evaluation, but from *this question* perspective it doesn't change too much. I mean if I go in search of possible trouble, I can find them also in ordinary methods implementation too. The question is not: "which one is faster", "more portable", "consumes less memory",  but what is the `behavioral` difference *apart* from the context where it used. At least, *I*, understand it in this way.