# 2 different types of Outlook EventHandler

Tags: c#, outlook, event-handling

What is the difference between:

```
Application.NewMail += Application_NewMail;           

private void Application_NewMail()
{
// implementation
}
```

and

```
this.Application.NewMail += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisAddIn_NewMail);

private void ThisAddIn_NewMail()
{
 // implementation
}
```

Visual Studio suggests the first one which is automatically added if hitting tap key twice after typing += while the 2nd is always what's shown in MSDN code examples. Are there any functional differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first one is a shorter version (introduced in .NET 2.0 i think). both are correct.

also, this is a duplicate
(see [+= new EventHandler(Method) vs += Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749868/new-eventhandlermethod-vs-method))