# Understanding event handling for incoming messages

Tags: c#, events, interactive-brokers

I am trying to understand a portion of code from the Interactive Brokers sample in their API. It is about processing data from incoming messages, and while I understand the general flow of event handling, I don't understand this one part:

```
ibClient.ScannerData += (reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr) => 
    HandleMessage(new ScannerMessage(reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr));
```

***What is happening in this line of code?*** I understand what is going on in the grander scheme of things, but not what is happening with the `ibClient.ScannerData += ([params]) => f(g([params]))`

The `HandleMessage` method is responsible for obviously handling incoming messages, and since this line of code is only run once, I believe this is telling `ibClient.ScannerData` information how to handle `ScannerData` information that is sent to `ibClient`.

This is what `ibClient` looks like in the backend -

```
public event Action<int, int, ContractDetails, string, string, string, string> ScannerData;

void EWrapper.scannerData(int reqId, int rank, ContractDetails contractDetails, string distance, string benchmark, string projection, string legsStr)
{
    var tmp = ScannerData;

    if (tmp != null)
        tmp(reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr);
}
```

Where `EWrapper.scannerData` is -

> ```
> void  scannerData (int reqId, int rank, ContractDetails contractDetails, string distance, string benchmark, string projection, string legsStr)
> ```
>
> provides the data resulting from the market scanner
>   request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is basically assigning an event handler to an event. Let's look at a simpler example with less parameter to help clarify the confusion. If you look at the `Button` class, it has a click event and the signature for the event is like this:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

So basically to subscribe to the `Click` event of the button, you need a method which takes an `object` and an `EventArgs`. So to subscribe to it you do this:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
```

Or this:

```
button.Click += (se, ev) => Button_Click(sender, e);
```

Or even short, you can do this:

```
button.Click += Button_Click;
```

They are all doing the same. They are saying when the button's `Click` event is fired, call the `Button_Click` method. The method looks like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code here
}
```

The `+=` is subscribing, or adding a handler to the `Click` event. You can add as many as you want. If you want to unsubscribe or remove the handler, you use `-=`.

In your case, the event is like this:

```
public event Action<int, int, ContractDetails, string, string, string, string> ScannerData;
```

So it is saying to subscribe to the `ScannerData` event, you need a method which takes 7 parameters (2 `int`s, a `ContractDetails` and 4 `string`s). So to subscribe to it, you do this:

```
ibClient.ScannerData += (reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr) => 
    HandleMessage(new ScannerMessage(reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr));
```

The `Action` delegate:

> Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value.

In your case it is an `Action` delegate with more parameters.

This `=>` is a lambda notation. Essentially it could have been like this:

```
this.ScannerData += new Action<int, int, ContractDetails, string, string, string, string>(
    HandleMessage
    (new ScannerMessage(reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, 
                        benchmark, projection, legsStr));
```

You can read [this](http://www.csharplearners.com/2011/12/30/wiring-events-lambda-expressions-c/) article or google *event hanlders with lambda* and there are plenty of articles.

Comment: Nice answer with good detail. One thing I would like to see added though is how to detach a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

`ibClient.ScannerData` is a list of event.

This adds a new event to the list:

```
ibClient.ScannerData += (reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr) => 
    HandleMessage(new ScannerMessage(reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr));
```

This takes event list, and make a call to all registered events:

```
var tmp = ScannerData;

if (tmp != null)
    tmp(reqId, rank, contractDetails, distance, benchmark, projection, legsStr);
```

Found some explanation on += operation on function: [+= new EventHandler(Method) vs += Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749868/new-eventhandlermethod-vs-method)

Comment: Would it be possible to add another event to the `ibClient.ScannerData` event list?

Comment: @Adjit yes, it will even be called many times for same handler attached many times.