# Event, some difference in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Difference between ' += anEvent' and ' += new EventHandler(anEvent)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550703/c-difference-between-anevent-and-new-eventhandleranevent)

What is difference between these two lines?

```
button1.OnClick += SomeClickMethod;

button1.OnClick += new EventHandler(SomeElickMethod);
```

Is there any difference between these two and if there is what are differences, which one is better?

Comment: Closed withing a minute. Must be some kind of a record, no?

Comment: We're the least-lazy lazy programmers around.

Comment: Apparently every programmer in the world has nothing better to do but sit around watching for and closing questions on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two.