# What is this C# construct doing?

Tags: c#

I have seen on another post this and its confusing me...

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

   protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
   {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
   }  

   public string MyProperty
   {
       set
       {
           if (_myProperty != value)
           {
               _myProperty = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

---

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.PropertyChanged += delegate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     actual = e.PropertyName;
};
```

I'm wondering about the last few lines are doing to be honest, why would the user be assiging a delegate to an event? Would't they assign a method to it (as an event handler) or even an anonymous method as the event handler?

I thought that events were meant to encapsulate delegates.....?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/550703/21727

Comment: event handlers *are* delegates

Comment: I've answered the question as best I can, but it's a bit of a confused question... could you try to clarify it?

Comment: So, for a handler this trivial, wouldn't lambda notation work just as well? myClass.PropertyChanged += (sender, e)=> actual = e.PropertyName;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax was introduced in C# 2.0
They are using an anonymous method here, rather than having to create an actual instance method of the class. It's generally considered cleaner.

In C# 3 and above, a Lambda expression could have been used as well.

Comment: An edit to include the lambda notation for the delegate would be useful, I think...

Comment: myClass.PropertyChanged += (x,y) => actual = y.PropertyName;

Comment: okay this makes sense, I think perhaps the syntax of an anonymous method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx makes it confusing since it contains the word delegate. And somebody said to me that you could have an anonymous method. I guess what they mean is a delegate with an anonymous method.

Comment: @Exitos: I don't see why it makes it confusing - it's creating an instance of a delegate type.

Answer (score 4):

You *always* subscribe to an event (or unsubscribe from it) using a delegate. Even if you do:

```
button.Click += HandleButtonClick;
```

that's equivalent to

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(HandleButtonClick);
```

When you say:

> Would't they assign a method to it (as an event handler) or even an anonymous method as the event handler?

That's exactly what the last few lines of code *do*. That's what `delegate (...) { ... }` is.

> I thought that events were meant to encapsulate delegates.....?

Events provide an implementation of the observer pattern, using delegates as the observers.

Comment: Shouldn't "You always subscribe to an event (or unsubscribe from it) using an event" read "[...] using a *delegate*"?

Comment: Jon, that's interesting what your saying about the observer design pattern are you saying that events were created to address this design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

This class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

> **MSDN** Notifies clients that a property value has changed.
>
> The INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to notify clients, typically binding clients, that a property value has changed.

This is used for example on controls like the Datagrid. It signals the control that the property has changed and the control should rerender.

**About the Event**

You always subscribe to an event.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.PropertyChanged += delegate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     actual = e.PropertyName;
};
```

is doing the same as

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(myClass_PropertyChanged);

void myClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     actual = e.PropertyName;     
}
```

or

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.PropertyChanged += myClass_PropertyChanged;

void myClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     actual = e.PropertyName;    
}
```

#### More Information

- [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `+=` adds an [anonymous delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to the event. Instead of creating a named method with the signature `object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e`, you can use C#2.0 syntax to create such delegates anonymously in the body of another function. Another way of doing it would be to use a more concise lambda syntax from C#3.5+:

```
myClass.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) { actual = e.PropertyName; };
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not assigning a delegate to an event, they are adding a subscriber to that event using an anonymous method.

Also, as an aside, the NotifyPropertyChanged method should be changed to:

```
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Since there is a potential race condition between the null check and invocation of the delegate.

Comment: null protecting the delegate will save you from weird, weird bug reports.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you are correct; events encapsulate delegates.  However, event handlers themselves are delegates.