# Two different ways of create a delegate instance?

Tags: c#

```
using System; 

delegate void D(int x); 

class C 
{ 
   public static void M1(int i) { 
    Console.WriteLine("C.M1: " + i); 
   } 
}

  D cd1 = new D(C.M1);
  D cd2 = C.M1;
```

Delegate instances `cd1` and `cd2`  are created differently above.

Are they equivalent?

If not, what differences are between them?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550703/c-difference-between-anevent-and-new-eventhandleranevent)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the IL generated via a tool like LinqPad, you would find that in this case both blocks compile to the exact same thing:

```
void Main()
{
    D cd1 = new D(C.M1);
    D cd2 = C.M1;
}
```

becomes

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldnull      
IL_0002:  ldftn       UserQuery+C.M1
IL_0008:  newobj      UserQuery+D..ctor
IL_000D:  stloc.0     // cd1
IL_000E:  ldnull      
IL_000F:  ldftn       UserQuery+C.M1
IL_0015:  newobj      UserQuery+D..ctor
IL_001A:  stloc.1     // cd2
IL_001B:  ret
```

Note that instructions are 2-5 are repeated in 6-9, with a different stloc since a new instance is created.

Answer (score 4):

> Are they equivalent?

Yes. Delegates created explicitly and delegates created using the [*Method Group Syntax*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) are equivalent to each other.

Method Group Conversion has been introduced in C# 2.0. In the first version of C# the syntax that you used for `cd1` was the only choice available for creating a delegate.