# Is += delegate {} the correct way to attach custom eventargs to a UI control event?

Tags: c#, events, eventargs

I have been tinkering with Events to gain a better understanding of their use in very general situations.  I'm surprised to find the following, so I'm probably heading in the wrong direction...the essence of what I'm doing is changing a button to a random color when it is clicked:

Windows Form

```
public Form1()       
{ 

ColorChanges KK = new ColorChanges();

KK.ColorEventHandler += handle_ColorChanges;

button1.Click += delegate { KK.ChangeColor(button1); };

}
```

Event Class

```
class ColorChanges
{

   *... properties & constructor*

   public void ChangeColor(object sender)
   {
   *... randomly assign color to ColorEventArgs*
   }

   protected virtual void onColorEvent(object sender, ColorEventArgs e)
   {
      EventHandler<ColorEventArgs> ceh = ColorEventHandler;
      {   
      if (ceh != null)
         {
         ceh(sender, e)             
         }
     }
   }

   public event EventHandler<ColorEventArgs> ColorEventHandler;
}
```

Custom Event Args

```
public class ColorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public Color xColor { get; set; }
}
```

Event Handler

```
public void handle_ColorChanges(object sender, ColorEventArgs e)
{
   if (sender is Button)
      {
       var ButtonSender = (Button)sender;

       ButtonSender.BackColor = e.xColor;
       }
}
```

So the *edited* questions are:

**Is use of the EventHandler(TEventArgs) Delegate useful?**  MS documentation indicates that syntax like

```
  button1.Click += new EventHandler<AutoRndColorEventArgs>(handle_ColorChanges);
```

is correct, but that will not reach my code to randomly select a color and an error

> "No overload for 'handle_ColorChanges' matches delegate >'System.EventHandler' "

so something like

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler<AutoRndColorEventArgs>(KK.ChangeColor(button1));
```

or

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(KK.ChangeColor(button1));
```

Error says that a method is required and if I use

> "No overload for 'handle_ColorChanges' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'"

Lambda expressions help *thanks for the supporting answers*

```
button1.Click += (sender,args) => KK.ChangeColor(s);
```

But that doesn't allow un-assignment and that will be required later...

An anonymous delegate has the same problem

```
button1.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { KK.ChangeColor(sender); };
```

*The crux of the problem is that my color methods or their delegates do not match the button delegate signature (object, event).  I don't care about the button args and want to use my own*  **HOW?**

Comment: The `new EventHandler` stuff is optional since C# 2.0.

Comment: Related question: [C# why shall I use “new” keyword when subscribing for an event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751247/c-sharp-why-shall-i-use-new-keyword-when-subscribing-for-an-event)

Comment: The questions differ primarily because I am asking about adding a delegate or EventHandler<MyArgT> where MyArgT:EventArgs is a custom event args and do not match the default signature of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the use of the delegate correct?

Yep, what you are doing is assigning an **[anonymous delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)** as your event handler. This is perfectly valid, however, the catch here is you can't unassign the event handler because you have no reference to it. You could keep a reference to it and do it that way (if required)

```
var clickHandler = delegate { ... };
button1.Click += clickHandler;
...
button1.Click -= clickHandler
```

If you need access to the parameters of the event handler you will need to add those into the signature e.g.

```
button1.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args) { ... }
```

The `new EventHandler(SomeHandlerMethod)` construct is the long way of doing things, it's synonymous to `+= SomeHandlerMethod`. Your code currently doesn't work because you are trying to actually *call* the handler inside the constructor when the constructor expects a *reference* to the method

```
+= new EventHandler<ColorEventArgs>(KK.ChangeColor);
```

> Is there a better structure for this?

Yeah, you can do it using even *less* code

```
button1.Click += (s, args) => KK.ChangeColor(button1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler<AutoRndColorEventArgs>(KK.ChangeColor(button1));
```

Instead of `KK.ChangeColor(button1)`, you just need to specify the event handler method name as you did in here:

```
KK.ColorEventHandler += handle_ColorChanges;
```

The event handler method signature should match with the `EventHandler` delegate.If you want to just call a method in event handler, you can use lambda statement like this:

```
button1.Click += (s,e) => KK.ChangeColor(s);
```

Or:

```
button1.Click += delegate(object s, EventArgs e) { KK.ChangeColor(s); };
```

By doing this you are creating an *anonymous method* and attach it to your `Click` event.