# C# EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, delegates

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void mydel();
    public static event mydel myevent;

    static void del()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called in del");

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myevent = del;
        myevent += new EventHandler(del);
        myevent();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

`myevent += new Eventhandler(del);` This line doesn't work...It generates Error "No overload for 'del' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the handler:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myevent += del;
        myevent();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Your event is not an [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx). Your event is of type `mydel`.

```
public delegate void mydel(); // declaring the delegate
public mydel myevent; // declaring an event of type mydel with signature void mydel()

public void del() {...} // this method fit the delegate

// myevent += new EventHandler(del); // myevent is not an EventHandler
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed that his event was declared with a different delegate. +1

Comment: I saw this Post..

"static void Hook1()
{
 someEvent += new EventHandler( Program_someEvent );
}

static void Hook2()
{
 someEvent += Program_someEvent;
}
And then ran ildasm over the code.
The generated MSIL was exactly the same.

So to answer your question, yes they are the same thing.
The compiler is just inferring that you want someEvent += new EventHandler( Program_someEvent );"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877/c-sharp-event-handlers


My question:
When both lines are same...Why the second line in my prog is not working??

Comment: @Bala: You need to use the same delegate as the one you declared your event with. So you need to do `myevent += new mydel(del);`

Comment: @Bala, DanielHilgarth comment is correct I hope my edit can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the lines

```
myevent = del;
myevent += new EventHandler(del);
```

just remove them and replace the syntex.

the right syntex to register to event is:

```
myevent += new mydel(del);
```

or

```
myevent += del;
```

but not as you did

```
myevent = del;
```

you should also always check before calling an event that it isn't null.

so your code should be:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void mydel();
    public static event mydel myevent;

    static void del()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called in del");

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myevent += new mydel(del);

        if(myevent != null)
        {
           myevent();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

to learn more on event and registering read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20550/C-Event-Implementation-Fundamentals-Best-Practices):

> The += operator is used to add the delegate instance to the invocation
>   list of the event handler in the publisher. Remember, multiple
>   subscribers may register with the event. Use the += operator to append
>   the current subscriber to the underlying delegate's invocation list.

Comment: OK. But the problem really isn't the assignment. This compiles just fine, because it is in the same class. It is odd, agreed, but not the problem of the OP. The problem really is the difference in signatures between the event-handling method and the `EventHandler` delegate.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yeah i know, that's what i've changed... the myevent event is of type mydel delegate, and the user used EventHandler for some reason

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it's working now, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Yes, but your answer declares something as the problem that really isn't the problem. You say *"the problem is with the line myevent = del;. just remove it"*, but that simply is incorrect. That line is not the problem. You are misleading the OP here.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code, then it will work like magic!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   myevent += del;
   myevent();
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```